# Nested JSON path with dot/period in azure

Tags: json, azure, command-line, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

The goal is to use the `az iot edge deployment update` command to change a module in an azure iot hub/edge deployment. The attempt to do this uses the property-path within the deployment configuration json to replace the image path. The problem is that there is a dot in a json property `properties.desired`  and attempts of escaping it have been futile. The file is a default azure deployment configuration file.

**Command format**

```sh
az iot edge deployment update --deployment-id <name-of-deployment> --hub-name <name-of-iot-hub> --set <json-path>=<new-value>
```

**First part of the deployment configuration (json)**
The goal is to change the value of `image`

```
{
    "content": {
        "modulesContent": {
            "$edgeAgent": {
                "properties.desired": {
                    "modules": {
                        "demoimage1-latest": {
                            "settings": {
                                "image": "demoworkspac2478a907.azurecr.io/demoimage1:6",
```

**The most obvious attempt**

```sh
az iot edge deployment update --deployment-id demoimage1-6 --hub-name iot-hubski --set content.modulesContent.'$edgeAgent'.'properties.desired'.modules.'demoimage1-latest'.settings.image=demoworkspac2478a907.azurecr.io/demoimage1:5
```

Gives

> Couldn't find 'properties' in 'content.modulesContent.$edgeAgent.properties.desired.modules.demoimage1-latest'. Available options: ['properties.desired']

**Status**

Many things have been tried using both bash (ubuntu LTS vm) and powershell (win10)

- `[properties.desired]`
- `'[properties.desired]'`
- `['properties.desired']`
- `properties\.desired`
- `properties`.desired`
- `properties.desired`
- `'..."properties.desired"...'`
- `'...\"properties.desired\"...'`
- `'$edgeAgent'[properties.desired]`
- `'$edgeAgent'['properties.desired']`
- `^[properties.desired^]`
- `^^[properties.desired^^]`
- ``[properties.desired`]`
- ```[properties.desired``]`

Comment: I solved this by not using this command, but rather deleting and redeploying the azure iot hub deployment. If anyone has a solution i'm still very interested! Also posted this as comment on the microsoft documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to manually strinigying the $edgeHub JSON.

```
az iot edge deployment update --deployment-id testedge --hub-name microwaves --set content.modulesContent.'$edgeHub'="{'properties.desired': {'routes': {'route': 'FROM /messages/* INTO $upstream'},'schemaVersion': '1.0','storeAndForwardConfiguration': {'timeToLiveSecs': 7201}}}"
```

However it doesn't do anything because of content being immutable.  Items that can be updated by `az iot edge deployment update` command: labels, metrics, priority and targetCondition.  labels and metrics do not allow values with ‘.’ in the name.

Comment: Awesome! Where did you get this info?